# Centos6.5 install vim7.4

Tags: vim, centos6

I'm trying to install Vim7.4 on my Centos6.5 system. When I do `make && make install`, the process get stuck on a step like below

```
installing /usr/local/vim/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1
```

and nothing happen ....

Comment: My default user is root.

Comment: You could try following the steps described in http://users.skynet.be/antoine.mechelynck/vim/compunix.htm - there is additional information in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/ilDDzBl1wC0